# How to make a remote mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, remote

I know that's it's possible to do a remote mysqldump if I specify --host but is it possible to create the file in the remote server as well?

Comment: I'm assuming Unix - cron a job to ftp the file 5 minutes after the dump.

Comment: It's unix, the problem is space on local machine.

Comment: Tar and gzip? Buy a disk? Even a memory stick?

Comment: @Vérace I just want to know if it's possible to do it remotely and not the solutions to be able to do it locally.

Comment: @added a couple of edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do the mysqldump directly to a remote location (like in other sgdb's).

Answer (score 3):

What about [piping a gzipped mysql dump over ssh](http://christiank.org/wp/2010/12/pipe-a-gzipped-mysql-dump-over-ssh/).

Answer (score 1):

You are better off just getting the necessary root access to ssh straight in and scp the file or dump.

If you cannot ssh into the server with root access but you simply interested in dumping the file inside the local DB Server, you have very limited options. In fact, I can only think of one option.

The only way to mysqldump data locally is not to use mysqldump itself but duplicate what mysqldump can do. Since mysqldump is capable of creating CSV files but you do not have OS access, you need to take matters into your own hands.

Login to mysql and run [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) .

Here is a sample for the [MySQL Documentation on `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html)

```
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table;
```

This requires [**secure_file_priv**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) be set to a specific folder. You also need the [FILE privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file).

To fully clarify the aforementioned query, keep in mind that the target system of [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) is the DB Server, not the client side. It says so in the MySQL Documentation:

> The SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statement is intended primarily to let you very quickly dump a table to a text file on the server machine. If you want to create the resulting file on some other host than the server host, you normally cannot use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE since there is no way to write a path to the file relative to the server host's file system.

Comment: so it's not possible to do it directly to the remote machine right?

Comment: But the OP's problem is that he doesn't have the space to create this /tmp/result.txt file.

Comment: @Vérace `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` only writes to the DB Server. It can never write to a client server like mysqldump can.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Isn't the OP's whole problem that he can't use mysqldump to another server? He has to generate the dump on the server before transferring it, but he doesn't have the space to do so - or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @Vérace Yes, that is his problem. My answer says `The only way to mysqldump data locally is not to use mysqldump itself but duplicate what mysqldump can do`. The origin of the dump is the DB server itself. It could never be the client. I am just showing that the only way to dump data in the DB server is from within the DB server. I also mentioned in my answer `You are better off just getting the necessary root access to ssh straight in and scp the file or dump.`.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Some confusion on my part I think. What you suggested (OUTFILE) - you are saying to do that on the client - i.e. the machine to which the OP wishes to send the dump from the server? What about backup consistency? Secondly, (me misunderstanding?) - am I not correct in thinking that your ssh/scp idea can't work for the OP because he doesn't have room for the dump - the point of his question? What about my replication and then backing up the replica/slave idea?

Comment: @Vérace No matter who issues the command from localhost in the DB Server or from a remote location, the source data is the DB Server and the target for the OUTFILE is also the DB Server. mysqldump is simply not the tool OP needs because he wants the dump shipped from an external source.

Answer (score 1):

@aF I thought that the solution mentioned by @tersmitten was a Unix *NAMED FIFO PIPE* - so you actually store a minimum of data on your system. Take a  look at the mknod/mkfifo named pipes [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156). Try a few of the links from Googling this ([intermachine IPC mkfifo example](https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=ssl#q=intermachine%20IPC%20mkfifo%20example)). I vaguely remember doing this for Oracle redo logs years ago.

A couple of thoughts - maybe you could mount a network drive from the other machine on your server and pipe your backup to that? Or the cloud - how big is it? Dropbox and other services offer this - Google drive?

[EDIT] (Pity I'm on the laptop today - no access to a machine to check out my theories about this fascinating question (gave you +1).

Take a look [here](https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=ssl#q=send%20file%20to%20another%20computer%20using%20pipes) - some results which jumped out at me were these ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat), [3](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/command-line-tricks-smart-geeks) & [4](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2006/11/06/netcat-a-couple-of-useful-examples/)).

[EDIT2] (My brain is really not working today! :-) )

Why not replicate to the remote machine and then backup the replica? Quick and easy replication is *_THE_* reason why MySQL won the F\LOSS database wars. Backup (at quiet times) allow the replica to fall behind at these quiet times quiet times and then catching back up won't be a problem. What storage engine are you using - MyISAM or InnoDB? What version of MySQL?